# How to display correct pointer values while stepping code with Xcode debugger?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, pointers

#### Problem:

When debugging following code it will display equal pointer values for `image` and `self.imageView.image` (`self.imageView.image` is uninitialized):

```
- (void)testImage:(UIImage *)image {
    if (self.imageView.image == image) {
        NSLog(@"EQUAL");
    }
    if (self.imageView.image != image) {
        NSLog(@"DIFFER");
    }
}
```

However, program flows through `DIFFER` just as it should do.

#### Question:

Is there way to display correct pointer values in Xcode debugger? / Why Xcode debugger displays equal pointer values for pointers that really are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set break point on `if (self.imageView.image == image) {` line

When execution stops at this break point write `po image` in XCODE Debugger and press enter then write `po self.imageView.image` in XCODE Debugger and press enter.

Hope i am giving answer according to your question.

EDIT:

If you want to view all variables at a time try this

[image]

See Upper right hand corner, select the middle option. then right click on any variable and select `Print Description of "your_variable"` option.

Comment: That did the trick, `po` command displays `nil` for `self.imageView.image`, just as expected. Do you know why (or how to fix) _variable list_ and _hover over variable_ displays incorrect values?

Comment: `Print description` thing is not as good as `po` for this case as it will print information depending on object type, for some object types it will not even print addresses. `po` is not trying to be too smart which is best thing there :-)